# What is to be done vs What has to be done?

Tags: tense, passive-voice

What exactly is the difference between the following two sentences?

> What **is** to be done?

or

> What **has** to be done?

Answer (score 1):

> What **is** to be done?

means, "What will be done in the future?"

> What **has** to be done?

means, "What must be done?"

The first sentence is expressing plans or intentions. The second sentence is expressing obligations or requirements.

Comment: I'm no native speaker but "What is to be done?" sounds a bit unidiomatic, does it?

Comment: @RubioRic "What is to be done?" is a bit old fashioned, but it is standard and acceptable. You are likely to hear this construction in the sentence, "There's nothing to be done."